# Is there a way to init database with schema.sql and hibernate at the same time?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am able to use them separately, 
with hibernate `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` 
or with a `schema.sql`

But at the same time once I put `schema.sql` on the classpath, the hibernate way will be ignored.

Execution order isn't important because the tables in schema.sql are independent from the JPA entities in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the reason why hibernate table creation was ignored is the loading of some initial data through data.sql.

If data.sql is present unfortunately it tries to load data between schema.sql and hibernate table creation.
It seems an unsolved bug in spring:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9048